# Venn-diagram n-ball?

Tags: probability

In probability with set unions and compliments it is sometimes useful to draw Venn-diagrams with circles, but under what circumstances would you need to represent similar information as a group of spheres that circles couldn't by extending Venn diagrams to higher dimensions?

Comment: Well. under what circumstances would they be more useful? What can Venn-diagrams of spheres accomplish that Venn diagrams of circles can't? What type of probability or event might that represent?

Comment: I see no reason to ever use balls rather than circles... and frankly... I don't see a whole lot of benefit of using Venn diagrams much in the first place.  They are useful to introduce sets and set operations to beginners at a simple elementary level as a way of visually interpreting and organizing data and intersections and such, but it quickly becomes cumbersome.  They are no more than a mathematical curiosity to me beyond that as you generalize to more than three sets or more exotic sets.

Comment: One of the greatest strengths of Venn diagrams is that *a beginner can draw them*.  Trying to use spheres and other higher dimensional objects ruins that strength.

Comment: As for what you are surely reaching for... see [Venn Diagrams # Extensions to higher number of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Extensions_to_higher_numbers_of_sets) on wikipedia.  Note that you can accomplish much with 2-dimensional shapes still.

Comment: It seems like you'd need to create all kinds of whacky shapes to always make sets connect the way you want in only two dimensions but which could be potentially much more easily constructible with simpler shapes in higher dimensions. I don't know that such a statement is even guaranteed and maybe there are set combinations that cannot be perfectly realized.

Comment: But again... who says you need to use shapes in the first place... You don't need to graphically represent how sets interact.

Comment: Well, look at it this way: you don't "need" to use vectors to represent the derivatives in a differential equation, but it certainly makes the math a lot more efficient and it makes generalizations a lot clearer. Similarly, if people are willing to make the leap to higher dimensions, there is probably a much more efficient way to organize set-relations with n-spheres or other hyper-volumes.